# matplotlib.pyplot y ticks same location for all plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need two axes in one plot with the same grid and fixed values for the ticks.
This works fine for some plots. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYfT8.jpg)

But sometimes the last tick on the top is not located at the end of the axis and now i have two grids in my plot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGqOX.jpg)

How i can set up the last tick for every plot at the end of the axis?

Comment: Your question is missing essential code to fully understand what you're doing.  Given the images, it is also hard to understand why you're creating two axes when just one ax would be much clearer. You could do something like `ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())`, but that looks like unnecessarily complicating the code.

Comment: Thank you, it work very well with set_ylim().